# Cant paint textures

Tags: texture-painting

I searched for all the questions around here and I still couldn't find how to fix this. I'm going mad already.
I've done tutorials and everything I could, unwrapped, set materials, create image, and still I can't paint on my mesh. It doesn't matter what I do, I can't paint on it. I really need some help to how to be able to paint the models, because I'm trying to make a game and I'm stuck here, can't move on on anything until I finish this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Wops, wanted to say, there it is.

Comment: Reduce to a simple set up in a new file - append just the single mesh object, clear the materials and start with a simple generated new image in the UV Image Editor set to Color Grid or UV Grid. IN the Node editor, set up a new cycles material with the image node referencing the new generated image from the UV Image Editor. In Edit mode, make sure the UVs appear on top of the image in the UV Editor.  In Texture Paint, see if the image now shows up and allows you to paint. If that is too complex, try setting up a basic cube for paint and look at the difference in set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: so it looks like your problem was the *Face Selection Masking* option (on the horizontal menu bar, the icon with a red and whithe chessboard), it allows to paint only the selected faces.

Old answer:

First you need to create an *Image Texture* in the material so that you can paint on something: In the *Node Editor*, enable *Use Nodes* and make a chain with your *Image Texture* node > *Diffuse* > *Output*.

I can't see your "PlayerSkin" image, maybe it's because it was not packed with the file. So you can use this image, if it exists, or another one, as the *Image Texture*.

Also, your unwrap is very special, you probably made a simple *Unwrap* but it doesn't respect the proportions of the topology. To directly paint on your object you can simply use the *Smart UV Project* option when unwrapping.

Comment: like this? 
(updated main post with more screens)
i selected the material, went to textures, selected image, created a new one 2048x2048, but i still can't paint on it. 
im not sure how to pack the image with the blend file? i mean, it's just a blank image cause i never got able to paint it.
I used the Smart UV project, and clicked the nodes, but still nothing.

Comment: well it works fine on my computer: create a new image, create the node chain, load the image you've created in the Image Texture node, select your mesh and unwrap > Smart UV Project, switch to Texture Paint mode, choose your color and paint. If it still doesn't work for you, perhaps pack your image and share again...

Comment: maybe you need to disable the Face Selection Masking option? (on the horizontal menu bar, the icon with a red and whithe chessboard), it allows to paint only the selected faces

Comment: Oh man, the face selection masking was the thing messing with me mostly i see now. 
I managed to paint, however, what i did was just adding a texture but not material, like you said, but i dont know if it will work for a game?
I really thank you for taking the time to answer and helping me!!

Comment: ok great! I don't know about how it works for games, though  ;)