# My mesh is grey and I'm not able to paint it

Tags: mesh, texture-painting

I'm new to Blender and had probably pressed something wrong when painting the mesh but it has some grey structures on top of it and doesn't allow me to edit it in texture painting.[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122965/cant-paint-textures. Seems Face Selection Masking is on in your case

Comment: Also looks like you have two other "sphere" objects overlapping the object you want to paint, and all are visible at the same time